# Sleep() in Window Form Application with visual C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, c++11

My question is related to **Window Form Application** and `System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(int delayTime)` in **Visual C++**.

My window form has a *panel*, in which there are 3 ovalShape named ovalShape1, ovalShape2 and ovalShape3. A button name button is next to the panel. Button is associated to a click event. What I need is when I click the button, the color of every oval shape will be changed to red after every 1 second (1000 miliseconds).
This is what I’ve done:

```
private: System::Void buttonClick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    this->ovalShape1->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1000);
    this->ovalShape1->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;


    this->ovalShape2->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1000);
    this->ovalShape2->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;

    this->ovalShape3->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1000);
    this->ovalShape3->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;

}
```

But for some reason (I don’t know), the application doesn’t work the way I have expected. The ovalShape1 just flashes and that’s all.

Maybe you know the reason!

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of Windows UI drawing optimizations. When you set the fill color of the oval:

- A new color is stored in FillColor property
- A repaint is scheduled to be done when your processing is finished.

So you modify the FillColor three times and schedule repaint for the oval three times. Then your code finishes and the oval is finally repainted.

You have to call `ovalShape.Refresh()` after changing its color to force redraw that control.

Comment: Solved the problem perfectly . thanks a lot for the quick answer

Comment: No problem. By the way, try to avoid `Thread.Sleep`, because it kills responsivness of your application (if you set too long time, modern Windows will mark your application as non-responsive). The correct solution would be to run the color changing method in a separate thread.